# Contact Details Returned Twice

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am trying fetch contact details such as Name, phone number, email and photo. attached to a contact in an arraylist.

But for a contact having both phone number and email address. I can see the same contact name twice at first with its email address & then with its phone number and is not shown as a single contact (which it should be).
Can anyone please help me out with this?
TIA :)

Ref.:

```
public ArrayList<User> getPhoneContact(String paramString, ArrayList<User> paramArrayList)
    throws CustomException
  {

        //Cursor localCursor = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList();
        User user;
        boolean flag;
        String s1;
        String s2;
        String s6;
        String s5;
        String s3;
        String s4;
        int i;
        int j;
        int k;
        int l;
        int i1;
        try
        {

            cursor = getNamesAndPictures(paramArrayList);

            if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
                user = null;

                i = cursor.getColumnIndex("data1");
                j = cursor.getColumnIndex("contact_id");
                k = cursor.getColumnIndex("display_name");
                l = cursor.getColumnIndex("data1");
                i1 = cursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype");
                s1 = null;

                do{
                    s2 = cursor.getString(j);
                    if(s2 == null)
                        return localArrayList;
                    //if(s2.equals(s1))
                        //return localArrayList;
                    user = new User();

                    s1 = s2;
                    s3 = cursor.getString(k);
                    user.setName(s3);
                    user.setContactId(s2);
                    user.setContactType(paramString);
                    s4 = cursor.getString(i1);
                    if(s4 != null){
                        if(s4.equals("vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2")){
                            s6 = cursor.getString(i);
                            user.setPhone(s6);
                        }

                        else if(s4.equals("vnd.android.cursor.item/email_v2")){
                                s5 = cursor.getString(l);
                                user.setEmail(s5);

                            }
                    }

                    localArrayList.add(user);
                }while(cursor.moveToNext());

            }
        }
        catch (Exception localException)
        {
          //localException
        }

    finally
    {
      //closeCursor(localCursor);
      closeCursor(cursor);
      closeDatabase();
    }

        return localArrayList;
  }
```

And:

```
private Cursor getNamesAndPictures(ArrayList<User> paramArrayList)
  {
    String str1 = prepareContactIdsString(paramArrayList);
    ContentResolver localContentResolver = this.getAppContext().getContentResolver();
    String[] arrayOfString = { "data1", "contact_id", "display_name", "_id", "data1", "mimetype" };
    String str2 = "display_name != 'null' AND ( (mimetype = 'vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2'  AND is_primary != -1 )  OR (mimetype = 'vnd.android.cursor.item/email_v2'  AND is_primary != -1 ) ) AND contact_id NOT IN ( " + str1 + ")";
    return localContentResolver.query(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, arrayOfString, str2, null, "display_name COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because you query the Data table which holds data rows , each row foe some kind of information about the contact, for example one row for email and one row for phone number.
if you want to get only the contacts you should query ContactsContract.Contacts table but then you will have to query for each of them the email and phone.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html